# Letters to predefined numbers conversion in one window

Tags: javascript, encryption

)
I have searched high and low, but i can´t find what i need. Or i´m to stupid to get it right ;-)

I need a page with several input boxes where i can type some text, and then an output area below each input, that shows the text converted to some predefined numbers.

example:

input: abcde fghi æøå (i need all kinds of characters like .,/: etc.)

output: 064 065 066 067 068 032

So it needs to convert like this:

"a"="064 "

"b"="065 "

"space"="032 "

(and yes, each number in output needs to be separated, or a space added after each number)

I have tried some different cipher guides in both php and javascript, but can´t get it to work. I did do an Excel document that could do some of it, but it had a limited amount of characters it could convert, then it started behaving weird. So i thought maybe PHP was the answer!

Any help is very appreciated
/Rasmus

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: Thank you.. I didn´t even realize that it was a standard char code scheme i was following.. Just made everything much easier :-)

Comment: Actually, your numbers seem a little off. 32 is the ascii code for a space, but 64 is an `@`. 65 would be the uppercase `A`, then `66` is B, and so on.

Comment: Hi Again. Yes you are right, it is a bit off. I wrote it wrong A is 065, but special characters is off, for instance i need Æ=019 æ=018, but in ascii it is Æ=198 æ=230 and therefore it can´t be done with simple charcode translation.. :-( So i need some other  way, maybe with an array, where i type in all the letteres with corresponding numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of elclanrs deleted answer, and for posterity:

```
<script>

// Using standard for loop
function stringToCharcodes(s) {
    var result = [];

    function pad(n){ return (n<10? '00' : n<100? '0' : 0) + n;}

    for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        result.push(pad(s.charCodeAt(i)));
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}

// Using ES5 forEach
function stringToCharcodes2(s) {
    var result = [];

    function pad(n){ return (n<10? '00' : n<100? '0' : 0) + n;}

    s.split('').forEach(function(a){result.push(pad(a.charCodeAt(0)))});

    return result.join(' ');
}
</script>

<input onkeyup="document.getElementById('s0').innerHTML = stringToCharcodes(this.value);"><br>
<span id="s0"></span>
```

#### Edit

If you want a custom mapping, use an object (I've only included 2 characters, you can add as many as you want):

```
var mapChars = (function() {
  var mapping = {'198':'019', '230':'018'};

  return function (s) {
    var c, result = [];

    for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      c = s.charCodeAt(i);
      result.push(c in mapping? mapping[c] : c);
    }

    return result.join(' ');
  }
}());

alert(mapChars('Ææ')); //
```

Using the character code for mapping seems to be a reasonable solution, using the actual character may be subject to different page character encoding.

Comment: Hi, nice code that has exactly the simple design I need, and the live conversion is very nice.. However, the same problem exists as stated in my commment above :-)